# How to read Data tab ids from dropdown list of selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have Drop down Data tab ids as an array. when i select option I want to get retrieve data tab ids.

```
<select name="users[]" id="users" class="form-control " multiple="multiple">
    <option data-tab_ids="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]" value="0">Admin</option>
    <option data-tab_ids="[9]" value="1">samjad</option>
    <option data-tab_ids="[2]" value="2">Mohamed Omar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have multiple option on `select` to get one array of all selected option ids you can use `map` method on selected options.

```js
$("select").on('change', function() {
  const ids = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('tab_ids')
  }).get();

  console.log(ids)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="users[]" id="users" class="form-control " multiple="multiple">
  <option data-tab_ids="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]" value="0">Admin</option>
  <option data-tab_ids="[9]" value="1">samjad</option>
  <option data-tab_ids="[2]" value="2">Mohamed Omar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the selected options by filtering out the non-selected and building a list of `data-tab_ids` values.

```js
document.getElementById('users').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  // Retrieved a list of all selected tab lists.
  let selected = Array.from(e.target.querySelectorAll('option')).reduce((res, opt) => {
    return opt.selected ? res.concat(opt.getAttribute('data-tab_ids')) : res;
  }, []);
  console.log('Selected tab lists:', JSON.stringify(selected));
  
  // Return an array view of a set of all selected tab IDs.
  let tabIds = [...new Set(selected.reduce((r, t) => r.concat(JSON.parse(t)), []))].sort();
  console.log('Selected tab ids:', JSON.stringify(tabIds));
});
```

```html
<select name="users[]" id="users" class="form-control " multiple="multiple">
    <option data-tab_ids="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]" value="0">Admin</option>
    <option data-tab_ids="[9]" value="1">samjad</option>
    <option data-tab_ids="[2]" value="2">Mohamed Omar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's it?

```js
$("#users").on('change', function(){
  array = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-tab_ids');
  console.log(array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="users[]" id="users" class="form-control " multiple="multiple">
    <option data-tab_ids="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]" value="0">Admin</option>
    <option data-tab_ids="[9]" value="1">samjad</option>
    <option data-tab_ids="[2]" value="2">Mohamed Omar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's my solve :

```js
const display = document.querySelector(".display");
const selectInput = document.querySelector(".form-control");
const setValue = () => {
display.textContent =selectInput[selectInput.value].textContent + " " + selectInput[selectInput.value].getAttribute("data-tab_ids")
}
selectInput.addEventListener("click", setValue, false);
```

```html
<select name="users[]" id="users" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option data-tab_ids="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]" value="0">Admin</option>
    <option data-tab_ids="[9]" value="1">samjad</option>
    <option data-tab_ids="[2]" value="2">Mohamed Omar</option>
</select>
<div class="display">
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question. The OP wants to retrive the `data-tab_ids` attribute of the `option` elements, not just the `textContent`.

Comment: ok sorry , try this : 
```selectInput[selectInput.value].textContent + " " + selectInput[selectInput.value].getAttribute("data-tab_ids");```

Comment: Please, edit your answer and paste this code there, if it solves the OP problem